Implementing Monthly Subscription Purchases in a Flutter Application
I have set up a 1-month subscription product under the "Monetize > Subscriptions" section in my Google Play Console. I am currently integrating the functionality to process subscription purchases in my Flutter app. However, I am uncertain about the correct method to use for executing the purchase. The available options are InAppPurchase.instance.buyNonConsumable and InAppPurchase.instance.buyConsumable. Given that I have configured a monthly subscription product, which method should I use to facilitate the buy-pay operation in my Flutter app? I need clarification on the appropriate method to use for this scenario.

you can use this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase

thanks for response @LuckyTrail , but i already mentioned that i use that plugin in my question
